# Reputation gained since last visit to reputation tab is wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-history

Per this screenshot [image: Screenshot of reputation tab]

I have 15,003 reputation, and have gained 4k since some point in time. Hovering over it says this has been since 'your last visit to the reputation tab'. That's wrong, because I visited it yesterday, and I haven't gained 4k reputation in a day (insert mandatory Jon Skeet reference here).

I presume it's 4k in a quarter, or in a year, or something. In any case, I think the popup is wrong, or the +4k is wrong. Or both.

Comment: The value there should be identical to the value highlighted in blue in the reputation sub-tab of the activity tab. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Oded yes it is the same (albeit rounded, i.e. 4k rather than 3965). And visiting *that* subtab makes it disappear. I guess I had assumed *this* was the reputation tab from the fact it said reputation in the box. It seems a little strange to measure it from the last visit to a subtab of the current tab. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Marking as by-design.

Comment: @Oded would be clearer if it said "sub-tab". Tabs are usually at the top, in the tab bar, so I assumed the whole pane was the "reputation tab". Since it isn't named, a guess is needed. Now, lower down, there is a row of links which act like tabs, and include "reputation". But they don't look like tabs, I don't use them, and the panes below show the information anyway. It wasn't a priority for me, but I wondered how to get rid of the unread numbers next to these "tabs" - but now I see you just visit the "tab". I think it could be clearer that it's a tab-bar, just part-way down the page.